# How to use ' in literal String in PostgreSQL

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, user-defined-functions, postgresql-9.2

I have learned that JPA- Hibernate does not support `INTERVAL` keyword. To deal with that problem I tried writing a function which in turn make use of `INTERVAL` keyword. All I need to do is to call this function from Hibernate.

Below is the function I want to write. It is throwing syntax error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getTimeStampAfterDeductingHours(abc varchar) returns TIMESTAMPTZ  as
$$
 select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL  ''' ' || abc || 'hour ';
$$ language 'sql';
```

**ERROR**:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "' "

Basically I want to use the input parameter in the SQL statement. I have tried many ways to include it. But could not do it.

Comment: When you get an error, always be specific about *exactly* what the error is. Show the exact, copied and pasted error text. It's also a good idea to always mention your PostgreSQL version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "' "
LINE 3:  select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL  ''' ' || abc || 'hour ...
                                              ^
```

That's because you can only use the `INTERVAL 'some-interval-here'` pattern for interval literals. PostgreSQL binds the `INTERVAL` tighter than the `||` operator, so you're doing:

```
(INTERVAL ''' ') || ...
```

which makes no sense.

In this case you must construct a string then *cast* it to `INTERVAL`.

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - CAST(''' ' || abc || 'hour ' AS interval);
```

I have no idea what you're trying to achieve with the leading `'`, and without seeing the input you send to the function I can't really guess.

Guessing  by the name of the function, you *actually* want to subtract the hours passed as an argument from the current timestamp. If so, you should pass an integer, not a string, and multiply the interval:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getTimeStampAfterDeductingHours(hours integer) returns TIMESTAMPTZ  as
$$
SELECT current_timestamp - (hours * INTERVAL '1' HOUR);
$$ language 'sql';
```